# using socket io on multi server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

As the socket.io explained , we can use socket io on multi server , please see the code first :

```
var RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis')
  , redis  = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis')
  , pub    = redis.createClient()
  , sub    = redis.createClient()
  , client = redis.createClient();

io.set('store', new RedisStore({
  redisPub : pub
, redisSub : sub
, redisClient : client
}));
```

Now I have some question :

1: If I want to run socket.io on 3 server and 2 instance on each one , how can I achieve that ?

2: Think a user connect to server 1 (from 3 server) , can socket.io handle room on three server , so users from server 2 and 3 get messages ?

3: Do I need node cluster to run socket io on three server ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as each instance is pointing to the same Redis store, all of your rooms will be available. If you want to run multiple instances of a node app on a single server you could use node cluster.

Comment: what about running on multi server ( multi node I mean)

Comment: What about running node on multiple servers? You need to make sure all stateful data is in a location that is accessible by all the servers. So if you're using express sessions, those should be backed by a redis store as well. That includes user generated content too. If a user uploads an image that will display on their profile, you can't just save that to the hard drive and expect things to work well.

Comment: So as long as they point out to one redis server , there is no problem , again there could be a problem, if redis server goes down , all of the node servers stop working , so does socket.io with redis store have any idea for such problem ? can I replicate the redis store on multi server , so if one of them go down , other remain , can I achieve that with current socket redis store ? thanks